# Why we don't observe spherical rainbow?

Tags: visible-light, refraction

We have seen or heard of rainBOW and [circular rainbow](http://www.slate.com/blogs/bad_astronomy/2014/09/17/circular_rainbow_rare_optic_effect_seen_from_the_air.html) but not any other shape probably due to the shape of water droplets. My question is why can't we see a spherical rainbow?

Comment: Uh...What would a "spherical rainbow" in distinction to a "circular rainbow" be?

Comment: @ACuriousMind thickness?

Comment: I think you could, but it might be rather pale, I am afraid. All you have to do is to use an appropriate (cylindrical?) light source. That might actually be a nice experiment.

Comment: it's an optic illusion. [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow#Explanation) said : The rainbow is curved because the set of all the raindrops that have the right angle between the observer, the drop, and the sun, lie on a cone pointing at the sun with the observer at the tip.

Answer (score 0):

the angle between incident light and refracted beams of a particular color is a fixed value.  you can rotate around the sun-to-observer axis which gives a ring